# Difference between .dynamic .dynsym and .dynstr in an ELF executable

Tags: linux, x86, elf

My preliminary knowledge is that:

- `.dynamic` contains libraries that the executable needs to load
- `.dynsym` contains external symbols such as `setsockopt@GLIBC_2.0`
- `.dynstr` contains strings of function requirements

Overall, I am a bit confused as to how these sections work together to create a binary - specifically `.dynsym` and `.dynstr`. So my question is two-fold. Are my statements above correct? If so, how do these three sections work together to create a binary?

Comment: `.dynamic` contains an array of tagged pointers that has pointers to both `.dynsim` and `.dynstr`. Your statements are correct, though not very detailed. However a quick Google search will find all the details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Are my statements above correct?

The `.dynsym` section contains a set of fixed-length records of type `Elf32_Sym` or `Elf64_Sym`.

Since these are *fixed* length entries, they can not by themselves describe *arbitrary* length symbols (strings) that the binary exports or imports.

Therefore these entries don't contain the strings. Instead, they contain an *offset* into `.dynstr` (in the `.st_name` field), and the symbol name is found at this offset.

So it's not true that "`.dynsym` contains setsockopt@GLIBC_2.0" and that "`.dynstr` contains strings of function requirements" (whatever that last statement means).

The `.dynsym` contains an `Elf32_Sym` or an `Elf64_sym` describing an imported symbol `setsockopt`, and referencing the offset of `"setsockopt"` string in the `.dynstr` section.

Likewise, "`.dynamic` contains libraries that the executable needs to load" is false -- the section doesn't contain *any* libraries.

It contains fixed length entries of `Elf64_Dyn` or `Elf32_Dyn`, some of which (such as ones with `.d_tag == DT_NEEDED` or `DT_RPATH`) may reference strings from `.dynstr` via their offsets. The dynamic loader interprets these entries in certain way -- for `DT_NEEDED` as "must load this other library", for `DT_RPATH` as "must search these colon-separated paths", etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was very clear and thorough. I appreciate it greatly!