# how to dump the .dynsym section of an ELF file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf

[As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156275/difference-between-dynamic-dynsym-and-dynstr-in-an-elf-executable) the **.dynsym** section is a bunch of *ElfN_Sym* structs arranged sequentially, so I'm trying to dump the st_name of all symbols but apparently there's something wrong with the way I'm parsing the file.

First thing I did was to get the index of the **.dynsym** section by iterating the section headers and comparing the **sh_name** field through the string table. Then I got the address of .**dynsym** by taking the **sh_addr** field:

```
Elf64_Sym *symbol = (Elf64_Sym *) shdr[i].sh_addr;
printf("%s\n", symbol->st_name);
```

This however is SEGFAULTing for some reason, what I am doing wrong and what's the right way to do this? Also, is there a difference between using **shdr[i].sh_addr** and **&shdr[i]**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This however is SEGFAULTing for some reason,

It `SIGSEGV`s because `symbol->st_name` is not a pointer to a string, it's an offset into `.dynstr` section where the actual string resides.

In order to print the name, you must `read` the contents of `.dynstr` into a buffer (or `mmap` the `.dynstr` section), and use `st_name` as offset into that buffer.